# How can i remove the white dots

Tags: rendering, particles, light, image, lighting

I dont know how to remove these white dots. I already tried to make the lamp bigger. More samples does not work aswell. I dont know what can I do?

[image]

Comment: Showing only the result makes it a bit of a guessing game. Consider sharing blend, or posting screenshots showing settings.

Comment: See also https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=remove+fireflies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those white dots look to me like light fireflies. To fix this, use denoising. You can enable this in the second render collections tab in the properties panel.